# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know that this error has been asked about so many times but I still cant find out how to avoid the null value i will just post the code and point to the line that cause the error

```
Private Sub loadRevFiles()
    ' load all the SVN information for the selected revision.'
    Dim a, b, RevNo, RevDataCnt As Integer
    ReDim filesAtRev(0 To SvnData(SvnData.Length - 1).RevNo)'this line throw the error'

    RevDataCnt = 0

    ' loading all the changes files into datastructure RevsionsReportDataStruct'
    For a = 0 To SvnData.Length - 1
        RevNo = SvnData(a).RevNo
        If RevNo > HeadRev Then Continue For
        For b = 0 To SvnData(a).changedFileNames.Length - 1
            If SvnData(a).changedFileNames(b).Contains(".dcm") Then
                ReDim Preserve RevisionsData(0 To RevDataCnt)
                RevisionsData(RevDataCnt).RevNumber = RevNo
                RevisionsData(RevDataCnt).FileName = SvnData(a).changedFileNames(b)
                RevisionsData(RevDataCnt).FilePathAndName =           SvnData(a).changedPathAndFileNames(b)
                RevisionsData(RevDataCnt).FileAction = SvnData(a).FileAction(b)
                RevisionsData(RevDataCnt).SVNNo = a
                RevDataCnt = RevDataCnt + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This is a function in a tool use to read dcm file find the changes and export them all to excel file whenever you commit changes you got a new revision 
For some reason this function is working very fine when the number of revisions is small but not working at all when the file number of revisions is high ..

Your help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Why did you tag this question C# and sharpdevelop when it's obviously in VB?

Answer (score 2):

If this line is throwing a `NullReference` exception:

```
ReDim filesAtRev(0 To SvnData(SvnData.Length - 1).RevNo)
```

then *either* `SvnData` is `Nothing`, *or* the last element in `SvnData` is Nothing.

It's hard to tell which that is as we know nothing about where `SvnData` is coming from, but if you're able to reproduce the problem, you should easily be able to debug through it and examine the values for yourself.

Once you've found out what's got the problem value of `Nothing`, you'll need to work out *why*, and either handle that case (if it's legitimate) or fix the cause (if it should never be `Nothing`).